# Meaning of fixed point in renormalization in quantum field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization

Is it correct to say that in usual context of renormalization (group) in quantum field theory, fixed point is essentially "equilibrium coupling constant" that must be reached regardless of cutoff? Or does it mean something else?

I am a novice just transitioning from quantum mechanics to quantum field theory, so help is appreciated.

Comment: No, the fixed point need not be stable. Fixed point means when you apply the coarse grain, the parameters don't change. Or one can think of it as $f(x^*) = x^*$, where $x$ are the parameters and $f$ is one step of coarse graining